# How to put image in a pdf generated by reportlab which is stored in DO spaces - Django

Tags: python, django, pdf, reportlab

I want to put my logo in pdf that is stored in digital ocean spaces. The code that I wrote was

```
pdf.drawImage('https://dummy-bucket.sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com/static/images/logo_name_header.svg', -0.10*cm,10*cm)
```

this throws the below error

```
fileName=<_io.BytesIO object at 0x000001D1CE603A90> identity=[ImageReader@0x1d1ce5e6f70] cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x000001D1CE603A90>
```

The file is accessible if entered in the address bar. I do not understand what this error is, please suggest me what to do?

### The complete code

```
def get_pdf(request):
    
    data= {
       ... some data 
        
        }    
        
        
    try:
    
        buffer = io.BytesIO()

       
        pdf = canvas.Canvas(buffer, pagesize=A4)
        
        
        pdf = base_temp(pdf, data)  #base temp is a pre designed canvas
        pdf.setTitle("Invoice")
        
        
 
 
 pdf.drawImage('https://dummy-bucket.sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com/static/images/logo_name_header.svg', -0.10*cm,10*cm)

        
        pdf.showPage()
        
        pdf.save()    
        
        buffer.seek(0)

        # sending pdf as a response
        response =  FileResponse(buffer)
        
        # setting the content-type to pdf
        response['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'  
        
        # telling the response that it is a pdf file
        response['Content-Disposition'] = f'inline; filename="{data["invoice_number"]}.pdf"'
        
        return response
    except Exception as e:
        
        print(e)
        
        return HttpResponse(str(e))
```

Comment: @KJ So what should I do. What is the solution ? Should I use the same image with a jpg extension or what should I do?

Comment: @KJ I added the complete view that deals with pdf generation, please check

Comment: @KJ I am sorry I changed the image path actually coz it is a logo, and also the approacg that I took was from a tutorial. I will edit the the path with the original image path